# Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to conduct an ANOVA for a numeric column titled "duration" in the df "Low.Ambiguity" with factors of Variability and Mixed. Both Variability and Mixed are factors with two levels.

I am trying the following code:

```
# Load low ambiguity experiment .csv.
Low.Ambiguity <- read.csv("Low.Ambiguity.csv")

# Conduct ANOVA for low ambiguity experiment.  
aov.ambiguity.low <- aov(Duration ~ Variability*Mixed, data=Low.Ambiguity)
summary(aov)
```

And receiving the following error message:

```
Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any insight into my mistake is appreciated!

EDIT -- also note that my df has more columns than I am interested in for this ANOVA:

```
> dput(Low.Ambiguity)
structure(list(Stimulus = structure(c(20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 15L, 24L, 22L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 17L, 
16L, 35L, 26L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 19L, 15L, 24L, 22L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
11L, 17L, 16L, 35L, 26L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 2L, 3L, 
12L, 13L, 19L, 14L, 24L, 45L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 26L, 
51L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 14L, 24L, 45L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 17L, 
18L, 26L, 51L), .Label = c("t1_block2_hoed3.mp3", "t1_block3_heed2.mp3", 
"t1_block3_heed5.mp3", "t1_block3_hoed1.mp3", "t1_block3_hoed2.mp3", 
"t1_block3_hoed4.mp3", "t1_block4_heed5.mp3", "t2_block1_hoed3.mp3", 
"t2_block2_heed3.mp3", "t2_block2_hoed5.mp3", "t2_block3_hoed1.mp3", 
"t2_block4_heed2.mp3", "t2_block4_heed5.mp3", "t3_block1_heed1.mp3", 
"t3_block2_heed5.mp3", "t3_block2_hoed2.mp3", "t3_block3_hoed1.mp3", 
"t3_block3_hoed4.mp3", "t3_block4_heed3.mp3", "t4_block1_heed1.mp3", 
"t4_block1_heed2.mp3", "t4_block1_heed3.mp3", "t4_block1_heed4.mp3", 
"t4_block1_heed5.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed1.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed2.mp3", 
"t4_block1_hoed3.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed4.mp3", "t4_block1_hoed5.mp3", 
"t4_block2_heed1.mp3", "t4_block2_heed2.mp3", "t4_block2_heed4.mp3", 
"t4_block2_heed5.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed1.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed3.mp3", 
"t4_block2_hoed4.mp3", "t4_block2_hoed5.mp3", "t4_block3_heed1.mp3", 
"t4_block3_heed4.mp3", "t4_block3_heed5.mp3", "t4_block3_hoed1.mp3", 
"t4_block3_hoed2.mp3", "t4_block3_hoed4.mp3", "t4_block3_hoed5.mp3", 
"t4_block4_heed1.mp3", "t4_block4_heed2.mp3", "t4_block4_heed3.mp3", 
"t4_block4_heed4.mp3", "t4_block4_heed5.mp3", "t4_block4_hoed1.mp3", 
"t4_block4_hoed2.mp3", "t4_block4_hoed3.mp3"), class = "factor"), 
    Duration = c(539L, 554L, 600L, 607L, 577L, 497L, 517L, 580L, 
    563L, 569L, 594L, 563L, 623L, 602L, 516L, 600L, 607L, 577L, 
    531L, 642L, 624L, 566L, 567L, 616L, 652L, 654L, 576L, 556L, 
    608L, 632L, 662L, 565L, 510L, 458L, 558L, 638L, 483L, 538L, 
    577L, 600L, 452L, 547L, 510L, 663L, 470L, 503L, 600L, 517L, 
    510L, 458L, 558L, 638L, 483L, 538L, 577L, 600L, 452L, 547L, 
    510L, 663L, 470L, 503L, 600L, 517L, 539L, 554L, 600L, 607L, 
    577L, 497L, 517L, 580L, 563L, 569L, 594L, 563L, 623L, 602L, 
    516L, 600L, 607L, 577L, 531L, 642L, 624L, 566L, 567L, 616L, 
    652L, 654L, 576L, 556L, 608L, 632L, 662L, 565L, 510L, 545L, 
    558L, 488L, 483L, 555L, 577L, 661L, 504L, 537L, 510L, 609L, 
    470L, 515L, 517L, 662L, 510L, 545L, 558L, 488L, 483L, 555L, 
    577L, 661L, 504L, 537L, 510L, 609L, 470L, 515L, 517L, 662L
    ), F0 = c(212L, 213L, 210L, 206L, 204L, 196L, 204L, 204L, 
    197L, 203L, 201L, 198L, 199L, 203L, 196L, 202L, 205L, 202L, 
    193L, 195L, 208L, 197L, 202L, 195L, 200L, 201L, 195L, 205L, 
    202L, 195L, 196L, 195L, 230L, 223L, 219L, 221L, 199L, 200L, 
    204L, 210L, 215L, 219L, 219L, 220L, 199L, 202L, 202L, 204L, 
    230L, 223L, 219L, 221L, 199L, 200L, 204L, 210L, 215L, 219L, 
    219L, 220L, 199L, 202L, 202L, 204L, 212L, 213L, 210L, 206L, 
    204L, 196L, 204L, 204L, 197L, 203L, 201L, 198L, 199L, 203L, 
    196L, 202L, 205L, 202L, 193L, 195L, 208L, 197L, 202L, 195L, 
    200L, 201L, 195L, 205L, 202L, 195L, 196L, 195L, 230L, 235L, 
    219L, 224L, 199L, 203L, 204L, 196L, 214L, 221L, 219L, 223L, 
    199L, 207L, 204L, 196L, 230L, 235L, 219L, 224L, 199L, 203L, 
    204L, 196L, 214L, 221L, 219L, 223L, 199L, 207L, 204L, 196L
    ), F1 = c(382L, 375L, 384L, 392L, 388L, 576L, 553L, 579L, 
    586L, 601L, 387L, 393L, 402L, 406L, 587L, 560L, 562L, 553L, 
    388L, 391L, 412L, 553L, 592L, 556L, 571L, 410L, 404L, 401L, 
    420L, 580L, 580L, 554L, 448L, 441L, 293L, 291L, 420L, 420L, 
    388L, 384L, 620L, 630L, 602L, 605L, 571L, 573L, 560L, 553L, 
    448L, 441L, 293L, 291L, 420L, 420L, 388L, 384L, 620L, 630L, 
    602L, 605L, 571L, 573L, 560L, 553L, 382L, 375L, 384L, 392L, 
    388L, 576L, 553L, 579L, 586L, 601L, 387L, 393L, 402L, 406L, 
    587L, 560L, 562L, 553L, 388L, 391L, 412L, 553L, 592L, 556L, 
    571L, 410L, 404L, 401L, 420L, 580L, 580L, 554L, 448L, 324L, 
    293L, 291L, 420L, 422L, 388L, 403L, 619L, 640L, 602L, 654L, 
    571L, 581L, 553L, 580L, 448L, 324L, 293L, 291L, 420L, 422L, 
    388L, 403L, 619L, 640L, 602L, 654L, 571L, 581L, 553L, 580L
    ), F2 = c(3001L, 2916L, 2948L, 2973L, 2947L, 1339L, 1381L, 
    1381L, 1347L, 1394L, 2943L, 2913L, 2987L, 2940L, 1353L, 1378L, 
    1325L, 1357L, 3010L, 3008L, 2972L, 1350L, 1397L, 1273L, 1319L, 
    2963L, 2991L, 3007L, 2989L, 1358L, 1347L, 1248L, 2837L, 2816L, 
    2780L, 2776L, 2684L, 2718L, 2947L, 2948L, 1247L, 1244L, 1293L, 
    1264L, 1348L, 1354L, 1378L, 1381L, 2837L, 2816L, 2780L, 2776L, 
    2684L, 2718L, 2947L, 2948L, 1247L, 1244L, 1293L, 1264L, 1348L, 
    1354L, 1378L, 1381L, 3001L, 2916L, 2948L, 2973L, 2947L, 1339L, 
    1381L, 1381L, 1347L, 1394L, 2943L, 2913L, 2987L, 2940L, 1353L, 
    1378L, 1325L, 1357L, 3010L, 3008L, 2972L, 1350L, 1397L, 1273L, 
    1319L, 2963L, 2991L, 3007L, 2989L, 1358L, 1347L, 1248L, 2837L, 
    2884L, 2780L, 2723L, 2684L, 2779L, 2947L, 3058L, 1205L, 1304L, 
    1293L, 1186L, 1348L, 1392L, 1381L, 1347L, 2837L, 2884L, 2780L, 
    2723L, 2684L, 2779L, 2947L, 3058L, 1205L, 1304L, 1293L, 1186L, 
    1348L, 1392L, 1381L, 1347L), F3 = c(3623L, 3607L, 3584L, 
    3576L, 3680L, 2831L, 2779L, 2915L, 2875L, 2712L, 3641L, 3590L, 
    3556L, 3584L, 2718L, 2856L, 2674L, 2659L, 3640L, 3656L, 3686L, 
    2726L, 2685L, 2866L, 2793L, 3516L, 3552L, 3513L, 3579L, 2932L, 
    2882L, 2882L, 3226L, 3121L, 3867L, 3319L, 3426L, 3269L, 3680L, 
    3357L, 2711L, 3129L, 2786L, 2833L, 2754L, 2771L, 2856L, 2779L, 
    3226L, 3121L, 3867L, 3319L, 3426L, 3269L, 3680L, 3357L, 2711L, 
    3129L, 2786L, 2833L, 2754L, 2771L, 2856L, 2779L, 3623L, 3607L, 
    3584L, 3576L, 3680L, 2831L, 2779L, 2915L, 2875L, 2712L, 3641L, 
    3590L, 3556L, 3584L, 2718L, 2856L, 2674L, 2659L, 3640L, 3656L, 
    3686L, 2726L, 2685L, 2866L, 2793L, 3516L, 3552L, 3513L, 3579L, 
    2932L, 2882L, 2882L, 3226L, 3315L, 3867L, 3722L, 3426L, 3464L, 
    3680L, 3642L, 2922L, 2735L, 2786L, 2880L, 2754L, 2861L, 2779L, 
    2882L, 3226L, 3315L, 3867L, 3722L, 3426L, 3464L, 3680L, 3642L, 
    2922L, 2735L, 2786L, 2880L, 2754L, 2861L, 2779L, 2882L), 
    Word = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("heed", 
    "hoed"), class = "factor"), Vowel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("i", "o"), class = "factor"), 
    F1.Mean = c(398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
    564L, 564L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
    398L, 398L, 398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
    398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 397L, 397L, 292L, 292L, 417L, 417L, 
    398L, 398L, 627L, 627L, 614L, 614L, 614L, 614L, 566L, 566L, 
    397L, 397L, 292L, 292L, 417L, 417L, 398L, 398L, 627L, 627L, 
    614L, 614L, 614L, 614L, 566L, 566L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
    398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 
    564L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 
    564L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 398L, 564L, 564L, 564L, 397L, 397L, 
    292L, 292L, 417L, 417L, 398L, 398L, 627L, 627L, 614L, 614L, 
    614L, 614L, 566L, 566L, 397L, 397L, 292L, 292L, 417L, 417L, 
    398L, 398L, 627L, 627L, 614L, 614L, 614L, 614L, 566L, 566L
    ), F2.Mean = c(2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 
    1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 2828L, 
    2828L, 2763L, 2763L, 2721L, 2721L, 2969L, 2969L, 1250L, 1250L, 
    1247L, 1247L, 1247L, 1247L, 1357L, 1357L, 2828L, 2828L, 2763L, 
    2763L, 2721L, 2721L, 2969L, 2969L, 1250L, 1250L, 1247L, 1247L, 
    1247L, 1247L, 1357L, 1357L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 1328L, 
    1328L, 1328L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 2969L, 1328L, 1328L, 1328L, 
    2828L, 2828L, 2763L, 2763L, 2721L, 2721L, 2969L, 2969L, 1250L, 
    1250L, 1247L, 1247L, 1247L, 1247L, 1357L, 1357L, 2828L, 2828L, 
    2763L, 2763L, 2721L, 2721L, 2969L, 2969L, 1250L, 1250L, 1247L, 
    1247L, 1247L, 1247L, 1357L, 1357L), Distance = c(36L, 58L, 
    25L, 7L, 24L, 16L, 54L, 55L, 29L, 76L, 28L, 56L, 18L, 30L, 
    34L, 50L, 4L, 31L, 42L, 40L, 14L, 25L, 74L, 56L, 11L, 13L, 
    23L, 38L, 30L, 34L, 25L, 81L, 52L, 46L, 17L, 13L, 37L, 4L, 
    24L, 25L, 8L, 7L, 48L, 19L, 110L, 115L, 22L, 27L, 52L, 46L, 
    17L, 13L, 37L, 4L, 24L, 25L, 8L, 7L, 48L, 19L, 110L, 115L, 
    22L, 27L, 36L, 58L, 25L, 7L, 24L, 16L, 54L, 55L, 29L, 76L, 
    28L, 56L, 18L, 30L, 34L, 50L, 4L, 31L, 42L, 40L, 14L, 25L, 
    74L, 56L, 11L, 13L, 23L, 38L, 30L, 34L, 25L, 81L, 52L, 92L, 
    17L, 40L, 37L, 58L, 24L, 89L, 46L, 56L, 48L, 73L, 110L, 36L, 
    27L, 17L, 52L, 92L, 17L, 40L, 37L, 58L, 24L, 89L, 46L, 56L, 
    48L, 73L, 110L, 36L, 27L, 17L), Included = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), 
    Talker = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("T1 ", 
    "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), Ambiguity = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Low", class = "factor"), 
    Variability = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Mixed", "Single"), class = "factor"), Mixed = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Consistent", "Inconsistent"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-128L))
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data using function `dput(Low.Ambiguity)` and pasting the results in your question?

Comment: dput(Low.Ambiguity) has been added!

Comment: The wrong part in your code is `summary(aov)`. Basically you are asking the summary of a function instead of an object. You should use `summary(aov.ambiguity.low)`

Comment: Ah, of course-- thank you so much for pointing out this error!